# How to check a particular bit of a "long long int" in C++

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to check a particular bit of a long long integer

```
long long int val=23355665641326;
int bit_no=32;
if( (val & (1<<bit_no)) == 0)
  cout<<bit_no<<"'th bit is not set\n";
else
  cout<<bit_no<<"'th bit is set\n";
```

the binary equivalent of `23355665641326` is -

```
101010011110111101010001001110110111101101110
            ^
```

we see, 32'th bit is set. But my code returns not set :(
how can i check the bit?

Comment: Assuming `int` is 32 bits, your code is undefined behaviour because you shifted a 32-bit type by 32+ bits.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you set, clear and toggle a single bit in C/C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit-in-c-c)

Comment: The digit literals like 1, 0 are integers in C/C++. So the expression 1<<32 will never be bigger than an int. I'm not sure if ((long long)1)<<32 would work. I wouldn't even try. I'd always prefer using std::bitset for bit manipulation in C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use  `1LL<<bit_no` to check the bit status of a `long long int`.

As you are dealing with `long long int` you need to use `long long type 1`
Because if you use normal `1(int)`, you can check upto `31 bit`
So just change the checking portion like this -

```
if( (val & (1LL<<bit_no) ) == 0)
            ^^^
```

Answer (score 6):

Your life would be easy if you use [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) instead:

```
constexpr auto N = CHAR_BIT * sizeof(long long int);

std::bitset<N> val(23355665641326LL);
```

Now you can test a particular bit as:

```
if ( val.test(i) ) {
      //bit at index i is set!
}
```

Or you can use the faster — but unsafe — version, as:

```
if ( val[i] ) {
      //bit at index i is set!
}
```

`test()` performs bound check and throws `std::out_of_range` if the index is invalid, whereas `operator[]` does not, in which case invalid index leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: The only proper way to do it in C++ is using std::bitset.

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz bit masking is no less proper C++. Not everything has to be done with classes

Comment: @Creris: classes are not important. Easy APIs are, especially if they dont cost you much, use them as much as possible. I've tested `std::bitset` with handwritten bit-masking, I didn't see any significant difference at all.

Comment: @Creris: there is no point of using std::string or std::cout but not to using other containers or streams. The only reason, the most people are still inventing their double-linked lists and do C-like bit manipulations is, they are not aware of better techniques. I've really loved bitset as I've written a debugging [tool](https://github.com/vheinitz/jeeamtee) for FPGA communication via shared mem. Bitset allows to use arbitrary bitlength without thinking about platform, compiler, etc. It is explicit and easy to use.

Comment: Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

To overcome with the need of adding the suffix to the check simply do something like this:

```
if(!!((val >> bit_no) & 1))
    std::cout << "not set";
else
    std::cout << "is set";
```

Comment: Apart from the double negation (useless, IMHO), I like this approach of shifting the value instead of the mask.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Well explicit conversion to bool :)

Comment: Nah, the first `!` *implicitly* converts its operand. An explicit conversion would be a `static_cast<bool>`. (-:

Comment: Touché! But you know what I meant.